# Oracle - How to return multi records from CASE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to return multiple records from "CASE DEFAULT".

eg:

```
Master.COLUMN1 IN (CASE '@InputString'
                    WHEN 'One' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Two' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'THREE' THEN 3
                    ELSE (SELECT NUM_BER FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN2 LIKE '%@InputString%')
                   END)
```

I tried with passing One and it returns 1. But when I pass 'four' it showed error like ORA-01427 single-row sub query returns more than one row. How can i solve this??

Comment: Each WHEN clause in a CASE statement can return only a single value, not a set of values.  The solution posted by @ABCade below is your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try it like this:

```
column1 in (CASE '@InputString'
                    WHEN 'One' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Two' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'THREE' THEN 3                    
                   END)
OR (column1 in (SELECT NUM_BER FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN2 LIKE '%@InputString%')
    and '@InputString' not in ('One', 'Two', 'THREE'));
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5bea/14)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the ORA-01427 error, because in select query in your else parts returns more than one row.

The below queries will help you:

```
WITH t AS
     (SELECT 1 string FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 2 string FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 1234 string FROM dual
     )
SELECT * FROM t
where t.string in ( case 'one' when 'one' then 1 else (select 1234 from dual) end);

output
_____
1

WITH t AS
     (SELECT 1 string FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 2 string FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 1234 string FROM dual
     )
SELECT * FROM t
where t.string in ( case 'two' when 'one' then 1 else (select 1234 from dual) end);

output
------
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decode`

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2     select 'A' as string from dual union all
  3     select 'B' from dual union all
  4     select 'C' from dual union all
  5     select 'D' from dual
  6  )
  7  select     string , decode(string, 'A',1,'B',2,3) as string_out
  8* from       x
SQL> /

S STRING_OUT
- ----------
A          1
B          2
C          3
D          3
```